# How to fetch current user data in flutter using firebase firestore

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

*image zoom 100%*
[image]Tried using this from online source but it is not working.

[image]

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(uid)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) {
  setState(() {
    // myName = (snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['name'].toString(); // change this
    myUsername = (snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['username'].toString(); // and this
    print(myUsername);
  });
});
```

Comment: can you make sure you reference path is matching with firestore console, try to print the `snapshot`

Comment: Its not printing.

Comment: can you include a ss of firestore console.

Comment: are you sure the collection name is `Users` ? or is it `users` ?

Comment: yeah add a screenShot of ur database

Comment: I have included the screenshot

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.